# How can I get the event when user type a URL and go to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I saw on a website that we can see when a use try to refresh the page ( using F5 or clicking the refresh button ) in this way:

```
if (performance.navigation.type === 1)
```

**My question is:** Let's say the user don't refresh the page but he type another URL to my other page. **How can I get that event?**

I say that because I have stored in my Redux state if user is logged in. When the page is type another URL, my state is lost. So, I want to catch that moment and check if I have a token in localstorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete that condition and put code in a useEffect and will work no matter if you refresh the page or type the url.

UseEffect will be triggered on any render.